# jQuery ajax form and Zend_Form file upload

Tags: jquery, file, zend-framework, upload

If i submit my ajax form from jQuery, and do

```
print_r($_FILES);
```

i get a list of files uploaded, 
but if i do something like this

```
$add_form->sound_file->isUploaded();
```

or

```
$params = $this->_getAllParams();
print_r($params);
```

i don't get my file in zend parametars, and i don't get it uploaded!?

Mayb the problem is with he context beng ajax?!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you haven't validated the form before you check the file.
Try posting the whole code or call

```
$add_form->isValid($_POST);
```

before you check the file.

Answer (score 0):

Uploaded files are found in $_FILES[], not $_POST[]